# Remove whitespace from inside html tags

Tags: ruby-on-rails, whitespace, strip

How can I remove whitespace from within html tags?

For example:

```
"\r\n\t This is a paragraph\r\n".strip
=> "This is a Paragraph"
```

But what about when:

```
"<p>\r\n\t This is a paragraph\r\n</p>".strip
=> "<p>\r\n\t This is a paragraph\r\n</p>"
```

How can I get ruby to remove the whitespace from inside the

tags (while retaining the p tags)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In rails , there is a method name 'squish', for example:

```
"<p>\r\n\t This is a paragraph\r\n</p>".squish => "<p> This is a paragraph </p>"
```

Returns the string, first removing all whitespace on both ends of the string, and then changing remaining consecutive whitespace groups into one space each.

It leaves a space. If you want to get `"<p>This is a paragraph</p>"`, I think you should use regex , it's more complicated than this. ^_^

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use it in view. You can do with the below statement.

```
<%= strip_tags("<p>\r\n\t This is a paragraph\r\n</p>").strip %>
```

suppose if you want to use it in controller you can do with this statement.

```
self.class.helpers.strip_tags("<p>\r\n\t This is a paragraph\r\n</p>").strip
```

strip_tags method will removes all html tags from string.

I hope this will helps.